# Passing information from one form to another?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How would you pass information from one form to another form, such as value entered in an edit on form 1 and when a button is pressed the information in the edit will be sent to a label on form 2.

How can I do this?

Comment: By adding methods and passing arguments? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's simply passing the content of an edit control on one form to a label on another form, you just set the `Label.Caption` (components on a form are published properties of that form).

Presuming that you've added the unit containing `TForm2` to the `TForm1` unit and created both forms, and that they both have their default names:

```delphi
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Label1.Caption := Edit1.Text;
end;
```

If you haven't already created the second form, you can do so and assign the label caption at the same time. This example shows how to create a new form, set the label caption, show the form and wait for the user to close it, and then free the form:

```delphi
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  NewForm: TForm2;
begin
  NewForm := TForm2.Create(nil);
  try
    NewForm.Label1.Caption := Edit1.Text;
    NewForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    NewForm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

For more complex needs, you can create properties to set or methods on the second form that you can call, passing information as parameters to the procedure.

Comment: Your answer is much appreciated!